# Bug in 4.6.3 and 4.6.8

Tags: civicrm-home

I performed a custom include/exclude search. When the results were returned, I checked the first record and the radio button '1 selected records only' was properly chosen. I selected a second record and it worked as well. I went to the next page and selected a third record and it worked as well.

I then performed the search again. This time, before selecting any records, I sorted by contact type. Again, I was able to select individual records. I then sorted by contact type again (to change the order) and when individual records were selected, the radio button showed '0 selected records only' and the action menu was disabled.

I saw this error in 4.6.3 and updated to 4.6.8 and the bug persists.

If this is not the right forum for bug reports, please direct em to the proper venue.

Thank you.

Comment: If you can reproduce this on a demo site (https://civicrm.org/demo), then you should report the bug on https://issues.civicrm.org/ . If you can't, it probably has something to do with your local environment.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're experiencing a JavaScript-related bug.  This can happen for a lot of different reasons - some of which are tied to your setup (e.g. a conflicting Wordpress/Drupal module) or even your browser settings.

You should be able to troubleshoot this using the [Troubleshooting JavaScript in CiviCRM](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35850) advice.  Before doing that, I'd definitely follow choster's advice and test this on the demo site (https://civicrm.org/demo) to help isolate what might be causing the issue!